# Windows How to verify user credentials?

Tags: windows

Is there any built in Windows script or custom script to verify user credentials (password)

as this way or similar

```
[a command or script] username password
```

Answer (score 14):

`runas /user:username cmd` This will open a command prompt if the password is properly entered.

There are other answers [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/410240/is-there-a-windows-command-line-utility-to-verify-user-credentials) on ServerFault.

Here is a Powershell [script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Verify-the-Local-User-1e365545) that will also perform the test.

Comment: You can use the variables to verify the password of the current user: `runas /user:%userdomain%\%username% cmd`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

net use \\%userdnsdomain% /user:%userdomain%\%username% *

%Errorlevel% is 0 if password is Ok.

Asterisk at the end of the sentence forces to ask for password.